# Example of contraction mapping theorem failing for strict metric map

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Is there an example of $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$

but a sequence $x_0,f(x_0),f^2(x_0)...$ doesn't converge to its fixed point?

where $f^n$ denotes repeated application.

Also, if possible, can you also explain the situation in a general compact metric space?

Partial work: I know there is a unique fixed point, and that the distance to it strictly decreases, and that there will be a convergent subsequence. But I don't think this precludes a counterexample.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the condition implies continuity via lipshitz

Comment: Sorry, my idea was bad. Try $f(x)=x g(x)$ where $g(0)=1$ and $g(x)$ decreases from $1$ in an appropriate way (probably very slowly). The idea here is that if the "contraction mapping constant" converges to $1$ along the sequence then you can encounter an infinite product that doesn't go to zero.

Comment: I don't think it can work with the fixed point at 0, since then your sequence strictly decreases and is bounded below. So it must must converge to 0 by continuity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the fixed point be $P$ and let $L$ be some point such that $L \not= f(L)$. Choose $\epsilon < (|L-P| - |f(L)-P|)/2$. For any $x$ such that $|x-L| < \epsilon$ and any $y$ such that $|y - f(L)| < \epsilon$, we have

\begin{align}
|y - P| & = |y - f(L) + f(L) - P| \\
& \leq |y - f(L)| + |f(L) - P| \\
& < \epsilon + |f(L) - P| \\
& < |L - P| - \epsilon \\
& < |L - P| - |L - x| \\
& \leq |x - P|
\end{align}

In particular, since $|f^n(x_0) - P|$ is decreasing, $|f^n(x_0) - L|$ is eventually always greater than $\epsilon$. So the only possible limit points of $f^n(x_0)$ are fixed points of $f$, and there is only one of those. In general, a sequence in a compact space with only one limit point has a limit.